# Creating anchor tags with multiple attributes

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, anchor

I'm trying to a create an anchor tag targeting some page, with MVC and Knockout.

The problem is: how should I write this if I have more than one attribute?

I was trying something like this :

```
{
    var hrefAttribute = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
    var attr1= "?attr1=";
    var attr1= "&attr2=";
}
```

And a view:

```html
<a data-bind="attr:{'href':'@hrefAttribute @attr1'+ id()}">
  Edit Having two attributes
</a>
```

Where `id` is jut an observable my mvv model.

Something like this would work if I have just one attribute, but what if I have two attributes?

Comment: Will these attributes be changing on the client side after they've been rendered by MVC?

Comment: no they are not , but I am building a table, this table would have attributes that are going to change ,and an anchor tag ,to delete this row etc...
without knockoutjs it would be very easy to deal with.

Comment: If it would be easier without knockout, why use knockout?

Comment: I think it is harder, cause I don't have that experience with knockoutjs as MVC and html. I hope ,solving such a problem with knockoutjs is easy too , but I couldn't figure a solution for it at all

Answer (score 1):

The [knockout documentation for the attr binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) shows an example of binding multiple attributes to an element.  In fact, it shows an anchor tag and sets the `href` and `title` attributes.

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: url, title: details }">
    Report
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        url: ko.observable("year-end.html"),
        details: ko.observable("Report including final year-end statistics")
    };
</script>
```

If the data is coming from the server, initialize your view model with data from the server using razor (or whatever view engine you're using):

```
url: ko.observable('@hrefAttribute')
```

Comment: Yes i think this would be the simplest solution, I would add a hidden input to the html document, containing the target of the anchortag.
While initializing the view model, i would pick this hidden input , adding to it , all the needed attributes ;)